# Draw a paired dna sequence inside a markov chain node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Once again I have gotten into trouble, I've searched everywhere but I have a difficult time drawing something which should look like the following[image]

I apologize for my poor "paint" skills. All circles should be same size. I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US,trees,positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}      
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=4cm]
\node[state]         [ inner sep = 0.7 cm ]        (0) {};
\node[state]     [label={[label distance=.2cm]75:Recombination},left of= 0, inner sep = 0.7 cm ]            (1) {};
\node[state]   [label={[label distance=.2cm]75:Coalescense},left of= 1, inner sep = 0.7 cm ]              (2) {};
\node[state] (b) [label={[label distance=.2cm]270:\textit{Left tree taller}},below of = 0, left of = 1  , node distance=4 cm ]  {$x_t > x_{t-1}$};
\node[state] (c) [label={[label distance=.2cm]90:\textit{Right tree taller}},above of = 0, left of = 1 , node distance= 4 cm ] {$x_t < x_{t-1}$};
\node[state] (a) [label={[label distance=.2cm]270:\textit{Same tree height}},right  of = 2, right of = 1, node distance= 4  cm ]{$x_t = x_{t-1}$};
  \node (s0) [below=0 em of 0] {\textbf{State 0}};
  \node (s1) [below=0 em of 1] {\textbf{State 1}};
  \node (s2) [below=0 em of 2] {\textbf{State 2}};
\draw  
    (1)   edge             node[above = .02 cm] {$\eta$}   (2)
    (0)     edge           node[above = .02 cm] {$\rho$}   (1)
    (2) edge[dashed]  (b)
    (2) edge[dashed] (c)
    (0) edge[dashed] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One thing: It's always nicer if you make your examples complete and compilable, i.e. containing a minimal preamble and `document` environment. In this case that would be something like `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}\begin{document} <your tikzpicture> \end{document}`. That way we don't have to figure out which libraries are required for example. Had you used any custom styles, then the definition of those should be included as well, of course.

Comment: Sorry about that. It should be able to compile now. Best Regards Simon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably, nodes with links could be done with `pics`, but here you have a brute force solution.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows, automata, fit, shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, node distance=1.8cm, ball/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, fill=#1}, ball/.default={black},
mystate/.style={state, minimum size=2cm}]

\node[mystate, label=below:\textbf{State 0}] (0) {};
\node[mystate, label={[label distance=.2cm]75:Recombination}, label=below:\textbf{State 1}, left = of 0] (1) {};
\node[mystate, label={[label distance=.2cm]75:Coalescense}, label=below:\textbf{State 2}, left =  of 1] (2) {};
\node[mystate, label={[label distance=.2cm]270:\textit{Left tree taller}}, below = of 2] (b) {$x_t > x_{t-1}$};
\node[mystate, label={[label distance=.2cm]90:\textit{Right tree taller}}, above = of 2, ] (c)  {$x_t < x_{t-1}$};
\node[mystate] [label={[label distance=.2cm]270:\textit{Same tree height}}, right = of 0] (a) {$x_t = x_{t-1}$};
\draw  
    (1)   edge             node[above = .02 cm] {$\eta$}   (2)
    (0)     edge           node[above = .02 cm] {$\rho$}   (1)
    (2) edge[dashed]  (b)
    (2) edge[dashed] (c)
    (0) edge[dashed] (a);

\foreach \i in {45,135,225,315}
\path (2.center) --++(\i:5mm) node[ball] (2-\i) {};

\foreach \i in {45,135,225,315}
\path (0.center) --++(\i:5mm) node[ball] (0-\i) {};

\foreach \i in {135,225,315}
\path (1.center) --++(\i:5mm) node[ball] (1-\i) {};
\path (1.center) --++(45:5mm) node[ball=white] (1-45) {};

\foreach \i in {0,1,2}{
    \draw[-, shorten >=0pt] (\i-135)--(\i-45) (\i-225)--(\i-315);
    \node[inner sep=2pt, ellipse, draw, fit=(\i-135) (\i-45)]{};
    \node[inner sep=2pt, ellipse, draw, fit=(\i-315) (\i-225)]{};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can define a `pic` which draws the linked pair. This one takes three arguments: the color of the left dot, the color of the right dot, and the style of the line which links them:

```
\tikzset{
pics/adn/.style args={#1 and #2 style #3}{
    code={
      \node[draw, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt, circle, minimum size=2mm] at (-.3,0) (A) {};
      \node[draw, fill=#2, inner sep=0pt, circle, minimum size=2mm] at ( .3,0) (B) {};
      \draw[#3, -, shorten >=0pt, shorten <=0pt] (A) -- (B);
      \node[ellipse,draw, fit=(A) (B), inner sep=1mm] {};
    }
}}
```

Now you can add the following lines at the end of your picture:

```
\path (0) +(0, .4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };
\path (0) +(0,-.4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };

\path (1) +(0, .4) pic { adn={black and white style dashed} };
\path (1) +(0,-.4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };

\path (2) +(0, .4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };
\path (2) +(0,-.4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to get:

[image: Result]

Just for reference, here is the complete compilable code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US,trees,positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric,fit}

\tikzset{
pics/adn/.style args={#1 and #2 style #3}{
    code={
      \node[draw, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt, circle, minimum size=2mm] at (-.3,0) (A) {};
      \node[draw, fill=#2, inner sep=0pt, circle, minimum size=2mm] at ( .3,0) (B) {};
      \draw[#3, -, shorten >=0pt, shorten <=0pt] (A) -- (B);
      \node[ellipse,draw, fit=(A) (B), inner sep=1mm] {};
    }
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=4cm]
\node[state]  [ inner sep = 0.7 cm ]        (0) {};
\node[state]  [label={[label distance=.2cm]75:Recombination},left of= 0, inner sep = 0.7 cm ]            (1) {};
\node[state]  [label={[label distance=.2cm]75:Coalescense},left of= 1, inner sep = 0.7 cm ]              (2) {};
\node[state] (b) [label={[label distance=.2cm]270:\textit{Left tree taller}},below of = 0, left of = 1  , node distance=4 cm ]  {$x_t > x_{t-1}$};
\node[state] (c) [label={[label distance=.2cm]90:\textit{Right tree taller}},above of = 0, left of = 1 , node distance= 4 cm ] {$x_t < x_{t-1}$};
\node[state] (a) [label={[label distance=.2cm]270:\textit{Same tree height}},right  of = 2, right of = 1, node distance= 4  cm ]{$x_t = x_{t-1}$};
  \node (s0) [below=0 em of 0] {\textbf{State 0}};
  \node (s1) [below=0 em of 1] {\textbf{State 1}};
  \node (s2) [below=0 em of 2] {\textbf{State 2}};
\draw  
    (1) edge    node[above = .02 cm] {$\eta$}   (2)
    (0) edge    node[above = .02 cm] {$\rho$}   (1)
    (2) edge[dashed]  (b)
    (2) edge[dashed] (c)
    (0) edge[dashed] (a);

\path (0) +(0, .4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };
\path (0) +(0,-.4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };

\path (1) +(0, .4) pic { adn={black and white style dotted} };
\path (1) +(0,-.4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };

\path (2) +(0, .4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };
\path (2) +(0,-.4) pic { adn={black and black style solid} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```